# Get a single value from a result set returned from PHP codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am working on PHPStorm with a codeigniter framework and the MVC architecture.
I need a function in my model that would query the `sysuser` table in my database and return the `uid` (User Id) when the username is passed.

**sysuser Table structure**

```
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
|   uid         |     name       |     username    |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
|      1        |       kim      |    kcdla        |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
|      2        |       Sam      |    sammyG       |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

In my function, if I pass, for example, the username `kcdla` I need to retrieve the `uid` as `1` so that I can store this to a variable as `$uid`  and return it to another function that will use it. But currently the result is an array and when I tried to access only the first cell from the array, I get an Exception.

**Code in Context**

```
public function getUserUid($username)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('sysuser');
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $tableArray = $query->result();
    foreach ($tableArray as $row) {
        $uid = $row->uid;
    }
    return $uid;
}
```

I need to use the `$uid` value returned from this method within another method as shown below.

```
public function getUserDetails($username)
{
    $uid = $this->userModel->getUserUid($username);
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('userProfile');
    $this->db->where('uid',$uid);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: call the function like this $uid = $this->getUserUid($username); instead of this $uid = $this->userModel->getUserUid($username);

Comment: Thanks combining this with the answer provided below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. As you need single row based on `username`, you have to use `row()`(returns Object) or `row_array()` (returns array) instead of `result()` because `result()` or `result_array()` returns result set

```
public function getUserUid($username)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('sysuser');
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row  = $query->row();
    return $row->uid;
}
```

Comment: Now I need to get details from two tables and pass them through the getUserDetails() method above. How can I get this done?

Comment: post a new question by clearing your all requirements with code

Comment: I can't for another 30 minutes since this question was asked only an hour ago.

Comment: if two tables are relational you may use JOIN to do that

Comment: My doubt is, is it possible to combine data from two different db tables and return them in a single `return $query->result();` statement in the `getUserDetails($username)` method?

Comment: Can you give me a sample please

Comment: They are relational and linked via the `uid` field

Answer (score 0):

call the function like this

```
public function getUserDetails($username)
{
   $uid = $this->getUserUid($username);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   $this->db->select("*");
   $this->db->from('userProfile');
   $this->db->where('uid',$uid);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();

}
```

Return the single row id like this

`row()`, returns only the first row. It's also an object, and if you need an array, you can use `row_array()`

```
public function getUserUid($username)
{
     $this->db->select("*");
     $this->db->from('sysuser');
     $this->db->where('username',$username);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     $row_values  = $query->row_array();
     return $row_values['uid'];
 }
```

As per your comment try this

```
        public function getUserDetails($username)
    {
        $uid = $this->userModel->getUserUid($username);
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('userProfile');

        $this->db->join('another_table', 'another_table.uid = userProfile.uid');
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $this->db->where('userProfile.uid',$uid);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
```

Comment: Now I need to get details from two tables and pass them through the `getUserDetails()` method above. How can I get this done?